# Model file for OpenCV's structured edge detector

Tags: c++, opencv

OpenCV implements [StructuredEdgeDetection](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/ximgproc/doc/structured_edge_detection.html) based on the random forest based approach outlined in ["Structured Forests for Fast Edge Detection" (2013)](http://vision.ucsd.edu/~pdollar/publications.html) by P. Dollár and C. Zitnick. The authors have published [an implementation for Matlab](https://github.com/pdollar/edges) and there's also [one for Python](https://github.com/ArtanisCV/StructuredForests), both of which also contain a pretrained model based on the BSDS500 dataset.

The OpenCV implementation seems to be lacking a pretrained model and I'm also unable to uncover what format the only constructor it offers expects:

> `Ptr<cv::StructuredEdgeDetection> createStructuredEdgeDetection(String model)`
>   The only available constructor
>   **Parameters: model** – model file name

The documentation also doesn't outline how to train the OpenCV implementation, so I'm left quite in the dark.

To recap, how to use the OpenCV implementation? Is a trained model available? If not, how to train one using OpenCV?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [this model](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_extra/blob/master/testdata/cv/ximgproc/model.yml.gz) from `opencv_extra` `ximgproc` test data.

If you want to train your own model, you can follow instructions on [OpenCV tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/d59/tutorial_ximgproc_training.html#gsc.tab=0).

Image:

[image]

Edges:

[image]

Code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\ximgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::ximgproc;

int main()
{
    Ptr<StructuredEdgeDetection> pDollar = createStructuredEdgeDetection("path_to_model.yml.gz");

    Mat3b src = imread("path_to_image");

    Mat3f fsrc;
    src.convertTo(fsrc, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255.0);

    Mat1f edges;
    pDollar->detectEdges(fsrc, edges);

    imshow("Image", src);
    imshow("Edges", edges);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it seems the information _is_ available, just hard to find since it's not structured that clearly.

Comment: Is it normal for this to take 30-40 seconds for a `190x480px` image having `40kb` size?

Comment: I debugged and checked...it's taking exactly 30s to complete the `createStructuredEdgeDetection()` step. I'm using the same model that you specified.

Comment: @mrid no, it's too much. Make sure you run in release and check the build optimizations

Comment: @Miki just checked, it's better now - it's taking 3-4 seconds now for most images :)  it however throws `AccessViolationException` on line `src.convertTo(fsrc....` for some images. Any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: @mrid probably those images are not loaded properly. Check that src is not empty

Comment: @Miki okay thanks. I'll try to check if the image has been loaded completely before doing any further ops on it

Comment: Where can I get the python version for training?