# Advanced denoise Image using Opencv

Tags: opencv

I am trying *denoise* this image to get better edges

[image]

I've tried `bilaterFilter`, `GaussianBlur`, morphological `close` and several threshold but every time I get an image like:

[image]

and when I do the `HoughLinesP` with dilatation of edges is really bad result.

Can some one help me to improve this? Is there a some way to take out those *noise*?

Frist try: using GaussianBlur, in this case, I must use equalizeHist or I cant get edges even if I use a really low threshold

```
public class TesteNormal {

static {
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java310");
}


public static void main(String args[]) {

    Mat imgGrayscale = new Mat();
    Mat imgBlurred = new Mat();
    Mat imgCanny = new Mat();

    Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread("c:\\cordova\\imagens\\teste.jpg", 1);

    int imageWidth = image.width();
    int imageHeight = image.height();



    Imgproc.cvtColor(image, imgGrayscale, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    Imgproc.equalizeHist(imgGrayscale, imgGrayscale);
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imgGrayscale, imgBlurred, new Size(5, 5), 1.8);
    Photo.fastNlMeansDenoising(imgBlurred, imgBlurred);     
    Imshow.show(imgBlurred);


    Mat imgKernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_CROSS, new Size(3, 3));

    Imgproc.Canny(imgBlurred, imgCanny, 0, 80);
    Imshow.show(imgCanny);
    Imgproc.dilate(imgCanny, imgCanny, imgKernel, new Point(-1, -1), 2);
    Imgproc.erode(imgCanny, imgCanny, imgKernel, new Point(-1, -1), 1);
    Imshow.show(imgCanny);

    Mat lines = new Mat();
    int threshold = 100;
    int minLineSize = imageWidth < imageHeight ? imageWidth / 3 : imageHeight / 3;
    int lineGap = 5;

    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(imgCanny, lines, 1, Math.PI / 360, threshold, minLineSize, lineGap);
    System.out.println(lines.rows());

    for(int x = 0; x < lines.rows(); x++) {
        double[] vec = lines.get(x, 0);
        double x1 = vec[0], y1 = vec[1], x2 = vec[2], y2 = vec[3];
        Point start = new Point(x1, y1);
        Point end = new Point(x2, y2);
        Imgproc.line(image, start, end, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1);
    }

    Imshow.show(image);
}
```

}

Second try: using bilateral filter:

```
public class TesteNormal {

static {
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java310");
}


public static void main(String args[]) {

    Mat imgBlurred = new Mat();
    Mat imgCanny = new Mat();

    Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread("c:\\cordova\\imagens\\teste.jpg", 1);

    int imageWidth = image.width();
    int imageHeight = image.height();

    Imgproc.bilateralFilter(image, imgBlurred, 10, 35, 35);     
    Imshow.show(imgBlurred);        

    Mat imgKernel = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_CROSS, new Size(3, 3));

    Imgproc.Canny(imgBlurred, imgCanny, 0, 120);
    Imshow.show(imgCanny);
    Imgproc.dilate(imgCanny, imgCanny, imgKernel, new Point(-1, -1), 2);
    Imgproc.erode(imgCanny, imgCanny, imgKernel, new Point(-1, -1), 1);
    Imshow.show(imgCanny);

    Mat lines = new Mat();
    int threshold = 100;
    int minLineSize = imageWidth < imageHeight ? imageWidth / 3 : imageHeight / 3;
    int lineGap = 5;


    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(imgCanny, lines, 1, Math.PI / 360, threshold, minLineSize, lineGap);
    System.out.println(lines.rows());

    for(int x = 0; x < lines.rows(); x++) {
        double[] vec = lines.get(x, 0);
        double x1 = vec[0], y1 = vec[1], x2 = vec[2], y2 = vec[3];
        Point start = new Point(x1, y1);
        Point end = new Point(x2, y2);
        Imgproc.line(image, start, end, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 1);
    }

    Imshow.show(image);
}
```

}

As suggested, I am trying use opencv contrib, using StructuredEdgeDetection. I am testing using a fixed image.

Frist I compile opencv with contrib

Segund I wrote the C++ code:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_vi_pdfscanner_main_ScannerEngine_getRandomFlorest(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
Mat mbgra = imread("/storage/emulated/0/Resp/coco.jpg", 1);
Mat3f fsrc;
mbgra.convertTo(fsrc, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255.0); // when I run those convertTo, I got all back image, that way I got no edges.
const String model = "/storage/emulated/0/Resp/model.yml.gz";
Ptr<cv::ximgproc::StructuredEdgeDetection> pDollar = cv::ximgproc::createStructuredEdgeDetection(model);
Mat edges;
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "chamando edges");
pDollar->detectEdges(fsrc, edges);

imwrite( "/storage/emulated/0/Resp/edges.jpg", edges);

jclass java_bitmap_class = (jclass)env->FindClass("android/graphics/Bitmap");
jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(java_bitmap_class, "getConfig", "()Landroid/graphics/Bitmap$Config;");
jobject bitmap_config = env->CallObjectMethod(bitmap, mid);
jobject _bitmap = mat_to_bitmap(env,edges,false,bitmap_config);


return _bitmap;
```

}

and I wrote this java wapper

```
public class ScannerEngine {
private static ScannerEngine ourInstance = new ScannerEngine();


public static ScannerEngine getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
}

private ScannerEngine() {
}

public native Bitmap getRandomFlorest(Bitmap bitmap);



static {
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");
    System.loadLibrary("Scanner");
}
```

}

this point is, when I run those lines

```
Mat mbgra = imread("/storage/emulated/0/Resp/coco.jpg", 1); //image is ok
Mat3f fsrc;
mbgra.convertTo(fsrc, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255.0); //now image got all back, someone have some ideia why?
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Kindly post your code so that we can help you debug it

Comment: check  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40042736/5008845)

Comment: Thanks for answer, I but the code in original post.

Comment: Can you also show output images? What is stored in lines when you use the above code? Hough Transform is very sensitive to the parameters, you can essentially filter out small lines with these parameters if you only expect large rectangle in images.

Comment: @Miki, thanks for your anwser, I've just compiled opencv with contrib, but to use the method, must I use a personal trained data in createStructuredEdgeDetection method, or exists some default configuation?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33318560/5008845)

Comment: @Miki, I am doing that way on using ndk and android:
`Mat mbgra = imread("/storage/emulated/0/Resp/coco.jpg", 1);
Mat3f fsrc;
//when I run this line, fsrc get all back image, do you have some ideia about why its happying?
mbgra.convertTo(fsrc, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255.0);
const String model = "/storage/emulated/0/Resp/model.yml.gz";
Ptr<cv::ximgproc::StructuredEdgeDetection> pDollar = cv::ximgproc::createStructuredEdgeDetection(model);
Mat edges;
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, APPNAME, "chamando edges");
pDollar->detectEdges(fsrc, edges);`

Comment: please edit the code into your question, with both java call and jni function

Comment: @Miki, OK I did in original post, thanks for help me.

Comment: try before the imwrite: `edges.convertTo(edges, CV_8U, 255.0);` The rest seems ok. You're seeing the image black because the images is converted to float type, with values in range [0, 1]

Comment: @Miki its done now!!! I am really happy!!! In some moments I will anwser those question with some results, Thank you very much !! I am woring in android api lvl 19 (4.4), really old device and its not slow!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Result about are strong, like this

Original Image:
http://prntscr.com/cyd8qi

Edges Image:
http://prntscr.com/cyd9ax

Its run on android 4.4 (api lvl 19) in a really old device.

That's all,

Thanks you very much